# tee messes up output file for large output

Tags: pipe, buffer, stdout, tee

I am running a program called dsk2ascii which reads a h5 file and prints the information into a file as lines like this:

```
AAAAAAAATTTGAGAAATTGAGAAATTATAT 2
AAAAAAATTTGAGAAATTGAGAAATTATATA 10
AAAAAATTTGTAAATTGTTTTTTAATGACAA 2
AAAAACAGGATAAATTACATCTTTTGGATAA 2
```

(A sequence of fixed length, space and then a number)

Now I wanted to print this into a file, but appending the results of subsequent calls. Therefore, my call looks like:

```
dsk2ascii -file testsample.h5 -out /dev/stdout |tee - >> outfile
```

`-out /dev/stdout` will result in the output of `dsk2ascii` to be printed on stdout. The `|tee -` I had to add because otherwise my `outfile` was truncated each time (despite `>>` being used)

For 42 subsequent calls, I end up with a very large (600 GB) output file. In this output file, 99.99% of lines are completely fine, but for some, I have a messed up result. I will have too short sequences, the space is missing, or there are additional newlines.

Is this some buffer overflow due to the large in- and output and if so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Any chance you're writing to the same file at the same time from different processes? The file being truncated means there's more going on than what you've told

Comment: `tee -a outfile` should append to `outfile` without needing the shell redirection